# Morris.js - How to add data labels to bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, morris.js

This is what I have right now:
[image]

And this is what i want:
[image]

Does this feature exist in morris.js? If not, what would be the best way of adding it?

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the code (and documentation), it doesn't seem to be there.  However, you might want to look at Line.prototype.drawXAxis() to add your own, or embed the chart within a `<div>` with a centred title below it - easiest.